# jest scripts failing with exit status 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, automated-tests, code-coverage

I have a couple of test scripts that are failing after the tests are all passing successfully and not sure the reason. I've searched the web with no solution that resolves
the issue.

Here is the output from the log after the execution of the script (`npm run patch-coverage`)

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'patch-coverage'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.18
3 info using node@v14.21.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prepatch-coverage', 'patch-coverage', 'postpatch-coverage' ]
5 info lifecycle ipln-scrd@0.235.0~prepatch-coverage: ipln-scrd@0.235.0
6 info lifecycle ipln-scrd@0.235.0~patch-coverage: ipln-scrd@0.235.0
7 verbose lifecycle ipln-scrd@0.235.0~patch-coverage: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle ipln-scrd@0.235.0~patch-coverage: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\<...>\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python312\Scripts\;C:\Python312\;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin;C:\MongoSH\mongosh-1.10.6-win32-x64\bin\mongosh_crypt_v1.dll;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\Users\gnorkett\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\gnorkett\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\gnorkett\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\DevUtils;C:\Users\gnorkett\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI;c:\terraform;c:\terragrunt;C:\Users\gnorkett\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\gnorkett\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\gnorkett\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle ipln-scrd@0.235.0~patch-coverage: CWD: <...>
10 silly lifecycle ipln-scrd@0.235.0~patch-coverage: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run patch-tests -- --coverage' ]
11 silly lifecycle ipln-scrd@0.235.0~patch-coverage: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle ipln-scrd@0.235.0~patch-coverage: Failed to exec patch-coverage script
13 verbose stack Error: ipln-scrd@0.235.0 patch-coverage: `npm run patch-tests -- --coverage`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
14 verbose pkgid ipln-scrd@0.235.0
15 verbose cwd <...>
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "patch-coverage"
18 verbose node v14.21.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.18
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error ipln-scrd@0.235.0 patch-coverage: `npm run patch-tests -- --coverage`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ipln-scrd@0.235.0 patch-coverage script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

All the tests are successful

```
Test Suites: 18 passed, 18 total
Tests:       74 passed, 74 total
Snapshots:   126 passed, 126 total
Time:        220.454 s, estimated 340 s
Ran all test suites.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ipln-scrd@0.235.0 patch-tests: `jest --config="./jest.config.patch.js" --runInBand --passWithNoTests "--coverage"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ipln-scrd@0.235.0 patch-tests script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ...\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-31T20_58_41_359Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ipln-scrd@0.235.0 patch-coverage: `npm run patch-tests -- --coverage`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ipln-scrd@0.235.0 patch-coverage script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ...\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-31T20_58_41_398Z-debug.log
```

This is the config file (`jest.config.patch.js`)

```
// For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property, visit:
// https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

const _ = require('lodash');

const config = _.cloneDeep(require('./jest.config.e2e'));

// The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
config.coverageDirectory = 'test_out/patch';

// reset collectCoverageFrom param to default value
config.collectCoverageFrom = ['resources/patch/patches/**/*.[jt]s'];

config.coveragePathIgnorePatterns = [];

// The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
config.testMatch = [
    '<rootDir>/resources/patch/**/__tests__/**/*.e2e.[jt]s',
    '<rootDir>/resources/patch/**/__tests__/**/*.spec.[jt]s',
];

// reset testPathIgnorePatterns param to default value
config.testPathIgnorePatterns = ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '.tmp'];

config.moduleNameMapper['^resources(.*)$'] = '<rootDir>/resources$1';

config.coverageThreshold = {
    global: {
        branches: 100,
        functions: 100,
        lines: 100,
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```

I've tried a few suggestions from [GitHub](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/9324)

Can anyone provide a solution to resolve the errors?

**Note**: <...> is a place holder for some potential restricted information as deemed by the company.

**Update**

I created a simple test as follows and I still get the same error after running the `patch-coverage`. Could it be the patch-coverage configuration?

```
describe('186-add-new-locales', () => {
    test('Empty test', async () => {
        const x = 9;
        const y = 5;
        const z = x * y;

        expect(z).toEqual(45);
    });
});
```

**Update** (Feb. 6/24)

Upgraded npm to **8.19.4** and node to **16.20.2** - error no longer appears. Does this mean there is a version problem?

Comment: Looks like one of the tests is throwing an error that exits the test execution. Have you tried running individual test files that are affected by your changes and seeing whether one of them causes this issue in isolation? That would let you narrow down where the source of the problem is.

Comment: Thank you @Dakeyras for your response. I ran each test individually (`npm run patch-tests <test.e2e>`) with no errors. I then ran each coverage test individually (`npm run patch-coverage <test.e2e>`) with each test passing but getting the same error as mentioned above after each one. Not sure what to make of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the coverage as one line of redundant code that would never be hit so removed that code block and reran the coverage script. Got 100% coverage.

Checked the lcov report that identified the line(s) not being covered.